# Selecting multiple lines in emacs open from Screen Gnu mode

Tags: display, emacs, gnu

Normally when open files with "emacs -nw" to edit, I can select line by <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>. The selected line or paragraph gets highlighted. But when I open file using "emacs -nw" in "screen" mode, then the lines are not highlighted. how to solve this issue ? Thank you.